# How can apply optimization for optimize route while launch google map url?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-urls

I want to redirect to device default google map app. So i am calling bellow url using some parameters but **optimization** parameter not working. So, any one have idea how apply optimization **true** or **false** while launch google map url.

[This](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=37.785834%2C-122.406417&destination=DFW%20Airport%20Rental%20Car%20Center&destination_place_id=ChIJOTBdvriBToYRlWVuQJEyyys&waypoints=T.C.%20Williams%20High%20School%7C343%2027th%20Ave%7CTGH%20Brandon%20Healthplex%7CSDRC%20-%20San%20Diego%20Recreational%20Cannabis%20Dispensary%7C26%20Federal%20Plaza&waypoint_place_ids=ChIJm-6u8Guxt4kRK1DJpQRJOjo%7CChIJDaWVJk6fj4ARQxE-WII8MLY%7CChIJb2-sbE_OwogRc176hwjB9Y8%7CChIJOZyfRiJV2YARNXxTa1XQ3rM%7CChIJt0bLuSFawokROLobA2qI8kg&optimization=true&travelmode=driving) is Output Url.

```
String mapOptions = [  
   'origin=${widget.currentLocation.latitude.toString()}%2C${widget.currentLocation.longitude.toString()}',
      'destination=${(destinationAddress.replaceAll(',', '%2C')).replaceAll(' ', '%20')}',
      'destination_place_id=${widget.routeDeliveryDetail.deliveryList[widget.routeDeliveryDetail.deliveryList.length - 1].placeId}',
      'waypoints=$wayPoint',
      'waypoint_place_ids=$wayPointPLaceId',
      'optimization=true',
      'travelmode=driving'
    ].join('&');
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&$mapOptions';
    print(googleUrl);
    try {
      if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
        await launch(googleUrl);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not open the map.';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

Comment: Your URL is wrong try this 
String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/api=1&$mapOptions';
Refer this Link
https://medium.com/@shivani.patel18/google-maps-url-launcher-in-flutter-54cf6388b381

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass "optimize:true" as the first argument within the waypoints parameter to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order.

```
String mapOptions = [  
   'origin=${widget.currentLocation.latitude.toString()}%2C${widget.currentLocation.longitude.toString()}',
      'destination=${(destinationAddress.replaceAll(',', '%2C')).replaceAll(' ', '%20')}',
      'destination_place_id=${widget.routeDeliveryDetail.deliveryList[widget.routeDeliveryDetail.deliveryList.length - 1].placeId}',
      'waypoints=$wayPoint',
      'waypoint_place_ids=optimize:true|$wayPointPLaceId',
      'travelmode=driving'
    ].join('&');
    String googleUrl = 'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&$mapOptions';
    print(googleUrl);
    try {
      if (await canLaunch(googleUrl)) {
        await launch(googleUrl);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not open the map.';
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```